# The following code of laravel in not working in sublime

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want the names I have stored in the array but it is not picking up the names besides showing this output!!!

```
<UL>
@foreach($customers as $customer)
<Li>({ $customer})</Li>
@endforeach
</UL>
```

Customers

```
({ $customer })
({ $customer })
({ $customer })
```

Comment: you have to print some value of your $customer, like `$customer->name` or `$customer->id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `<Li>({ $customer})</Li>` to `<li>{{ $customer }}</li>`

It is also better not to use caps in HTML tags (use `li` instead of `Li` for example).

Answer (score 1):

Your blade tag isn't right. You appear to be using a bracket and a curly brace. But you should just be using two curly braces such as `{{customer}}` rather than `({customer})`.

Try this:

```
<ul>
    @foreach($customers as $customer)
       <li>{{ $customer}}</li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```